# Ruby: Text Log Files - undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I'm getting the above error when I try to run the below code ... any advise?

**Input**

```
a1 =
[["10/10/2013", "user1", "machine1", "application1", "IN", "8:40:37"],
 ["10/10/2013", "user2", "machine2", "application2", "IN", "8:42:21"],
 ["10/10/2013", "user1", "machine1", "application1", "OUT", "8:43:07"],
 ["10/10/2013", "user2", "machine2", "application2", "OUT", "8:44:13"],
 ["10/10/2013", "user3", "machine3", "application1", "IN", "8:45:48"]]
```

**Desired Output**

```
output_array = 
 [["10/10/2013", "user1", "machine1", "application1", "8:40:37", "8:43:07"],
  ["10/10/2013", "user2", "machine2", "application2", "8:42:21", "8:44:13"],
  ["10/10/2013", "user3", "machine3", "application1", "8:45:48", "N/A"]]
```

**Code**

```
output_array = []
curr_row = []
i = 0
r = 0


while i < a1.length
 curr_row = a1[i]
 r += 1

if (curr_row[0]== a1[r][0]) 
 if (curr_row[1] == a1[r][1]) 
  if  (curr_row[2] == a1[r][2]) 
    if (curr_row[3] == a1[r][3]) 
      if (curr_row[4] != a1[r][4])
        output_array2 << "#{curr_row[0]} #{curr_row[1]} #{curr_row[2]} #{curr_row[3]} #   {curr_row[4]} #{a1[r][c+4]} #{a1[r][c+5]}"
      end
    end
  end
 end  
 else
 output_array << "#{curr_row}  N/A"
 end
i+=1
end
```

When you run this, I get an error message ...

**Error**

```
 in `<top (required)>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Am I doing something wrong here? or can we simplify this ?

Comment: I don't know what your code is supposed to do, but all those nested `if` statements can be replaced by something like `if (0..3).all?{|i|curr_row[i]==a1[r][i]}&&curr_row[4]!=a1[r][4]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, what is your logic, but the error you are getting because you are doing `r += 1` just after starting while loop. so In the last iteration, `a1[r]` will become nil, as value of `r` will be more than length of array `a1` in that iteration.

Comment: hi Saurabh, I was trying to combine 2 lines into one based on IN & OUT Times i.e.

Comment: On a given date, user1 using application1 on machine1 at a start time (IN) - when he first fired up his application  .... and combine with last use time i.e. (OUT time) ... in the above example...
Desired output [1st line]
     ["10/10/2013", "user1", "machine1", "application1", "8:40:37", "8:43:07"] ... 8:40:37 is the IN time and 8:43:07 is the OUT time for user1 using machine 1 using application1.